# Regexp equivalence

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm trying to write a regular expression that achieves the same result as `grep -w`.

What I have come up for now is:

```
var regex = /([^\w]|^)word_to_search([^\w]|$)/;
```

and it seems to work correctly.

Is there a "better" solution that you are aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using word boundaries should be simpler as equivalent of `grep -w`:

```
/\bword_to_search\b/
```

As per `man grep`:

> `-w, --word-regexp`
>      Select  only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must
>                 either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must  be
>                 either  at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are
>                 letters, digits, and the underscore.

Comment: Thank you, I did read the man grep and I converted the behaviour the best I could. However, I was not aware of the \b option :-)